# ColdFusion with application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I'm trying to understand ColdFusion, with that being said, should the application.cfc file work with just.. I don't need any html tags or anything?

```
<cfcomponent>
 <cfset This.name = "TestApplication">
 <cfset This.clientStorage = "jeb48_shoppingcart">
 <cfset This.clientmanagement="True">
 <cfset This.loginstorage="Session">
 <cfset This.sessionmanagement="True">
 <cfset This.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,10,0)#">
 <cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#">
</cfcomponent>
```

Also, is the clientStorage statement correct if that is my correct datasource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need any HTML or Javascript inside your Application.cfc. It will contain all the application wide settings and some predefined methods that gets executed on some particular event like onApplicationStart(),onSessionStart() etc.

For more infomation on Application.cfc , Follow [Learn CF In A Week](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/) article.

Yes your clientStorage statement is correct, If that's your correct datasource. As per my knowledge it will use that particular database to create some tables and store the client data.

Comment: @drago354: Have you configured your site properly with correct mapping handlers in IIS?

Comment: This is a university server. I don't have any control over configurations. Good thought, though.